# AJAX History with uninterrupted Music

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5-audio, browser-history

Good evenig,

I got a problem with my webproject:

When a user clicks a internal link on the page, the new content is loaded by AJAX.
In another `<div>` there is a `<audio>`element, that isn't interrupted by this action.
The problem is, that there is no history, so clicking the browsers back button will get the user to the external page he came from. 
How can I fix this problem?

I know that it works, because on [beatport.com](http://beatport.com) they managed to do it.

Comment: I don't see beatport doing what you're saying. When you click on an internal link, it takes you to a new page, there isn't AJAX. Can you provide an example to demonstrate what you mean on beatport?

Comment: Ahh now I see. I believe it has to do with HTML5 `pushState` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history , http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html . You can use this library to get better cross-browser compatibility - https://github.com/balupton/History.js/